# ArcGIS Python API wont run in Docker

Tags: arcgis-python-api, docker

I built a Docker container to run one of our ArcGIS Python API scripts. It ran for a couple of months successfully.  Recently I added some minor enhancements and rebuilt the Docker image.  Thereafter, the ArcGIS API quit working properly when run in the Docker container.  I decided to reduce the script down to this and it still throws an error (see below).  This is the script:

```
from arcgis.gis import GIS
gis = GIS(settings['myurl'], settings['myusername'], settings['mypassword'],verify_cert=False)
```

This is the error message:

> sh-4.4# python3.9 test.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/app/test.py", line 2, in 
> gis = GIS('https://******','****','****')   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcgis/gis/**init**.py", line
> 585, in **init**
> raise e   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcgis/gis/**init**.py", line
> 524, in **init**
> self._portal = _portalpy.Portal(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcgis/gis/_impl/_portalpy.py",
> line 205, in **init**
> self.con = Connection(   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcgis/gis/_impl/_con/_connection.py",
> line 344, in **init**
> self._create_session()   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/arcgis/gis/_impl/_con/_connection.py",
> line 521, in _create_session
> max_retries=Retry( TypeError: **init**() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method_whitelist'

This is the Docker file:

```
FROM [my org]/cloud/ubi/python:3.9
WORKDIR /app
COPY . .
RUN yum install -y krb5-libs krb5-workstation krb5-devel gcc
RUN pip3.9 install -r ./src/requirements.txt
RUN chmod 744 ./src/everyminute_run.sh
RUN chmod 744 ./src/everyhour_run.sh
RUN chmod 744 ./src/everynight_run.sh
```

This is the requirements.txt

```
psycopg2-binary
oracledb
arcgis
```

Note:  I tried the current and the previous versions of the ArcGIS library and they both produced the same error message.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue. I was able to solve it by downgrading the Python library 'urllib3' back to 1.26.14 in my requirements.txt file.

ie.
**urllib3==1.26.14**